# Reset the client secret of Azure Service Principal using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, service-principal, azure-service-principal

Using powershell commands i want to reset the Service Principal client secret.

I followed the below steps from the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-5.8.0
but it  didnot reset the password

```
Remove-AzADSpCredential -DisplayName ServicePrincipalName
$newCredential = New-AzADSpCredential -ServicePrincipalName ServicePrincipalName
```

can you tell what i am doing wrong. I just want to reset the secret and have new one

I executed the above command and then i went to the app registration of that service principal and there i went to certificates & secrets i see it has not createed new secret.

Using bash i am able to reset the password by executing the below command but i want it to be done using powershell command

```
az ad sp credential reset --name
```

Comment: SharePoint? Stored Procedure? What does `SP` mean ? Don't make people guess.

Comment: SP - Service Principal in Azure AD .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Service Principal in azure ad

Comment: What you mean `but it did not reset the password`, how did you know that?

Comment: @JoyWang I wento the app registration of that service principal and there i went to certificates & secrets i see it has not createed new secret.

Comment: @ashish edit the question so people don't have to guess. Explain what's wrong and how you decided there's a problem *in the question itself*, not the comments. You may be looking at the wrong place, or for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I went to the app registration of that service principal and there I went to certificates & secrets I see it has not created new secret.

Well, actually the command `New-AzADSpCredential` did create a new secret for you.
Firstly, you need to know the relationship between App Registration(AD App) and Service principal, see [Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

In short, the service principal is the local representation for the AD App in a specific tenant. When you create the secret for the service principal, it will not appear in the `Certificates & secrets` blade, you can just get it with [`Get-AzADSpCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadspcredential?view=azps-5.8.0).

If you want to reset the secret that you can find in the portal, you need to reset the sceret for the AD App(i.e. App Registration) via [`Remove-AzADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azadappcredential?view=azps-5.8.0) and [`New-AzADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-5.8.0).

You could refer to the sample below, it resets a secret with value `ce96a0ed-5ae8-4a5a-9b3c-630da9ea3023`, it is valid for one year, you can find it in the portal.

```
$obj = (Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName joyappv2).ObjectId
Remove-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $obj -Force
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "ce96a0ed-5ae8-4a5a-9b3c-630da9ea3023" -AsPlainText -Force
$date = Get-Date
$newCredential = New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $obj -Password $azurePassword -StartDate $date -EndDate $date.AddYears(1)
```

**Note:** You could not get the secret value again after creating it, so please store it when creating.

Comment: here we are setting a password is it possible thhhh it can auto generate a password?

Comment: @ashish In this command, `-Password` parameter is required, if you don't want to give a specific value, simply use `$azurePassword = New-Guid | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` to generate a guid as the password.